# How to Mimic Table Relationships in Dropbox Datastore API

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm wondering what the best way to handle 1-to-many table relationships when using the Dropbox datastore. Let's say I have a `house` table, and each house can have many `people`.

```
[house]
- kitchen
- roof
- people (many)
```

And people have attributes of their own:

```
[people]
- name
- gender
```

I can think of two possible approaches:

---

**Approach 1: Serialize the people and embed them in a `DBList`**

```
[house]
- kitchen: traditional
- roof: tile
- people: [Bob-male, Sally-female]
```

This requires parsing the data every time you pull it out of the datastore.

---

**Approach 2: Make a `people` table, track their record IDs in `house`**

```
[house]
- kitchen: traditional
- roof: tile
- people: [a3xy, t7e1]

[people]
- recordId: a3xy
- name:Bob
- gender:male
-----
- recordId: t7e1
- name: Sally
- gender:female
```

After querying the house, this requires doing an additional query with the people record IDs to get their data.

---

Are these the only ways to achieve table relationships in the Dropbox Datastore API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two typical ways to model relationships. In particular, that looks like a 1:many relationship. There are also 1:1 relationships (where just including the other data in the record is common), many:1 relationships (which are just the reverse of the 1:many relationship), and many:many relationships, which are typically modeled with a "junction table" (e.g. HouseToPerson).

Your first approach looks like a denormalized approach, more common in NoSQL databases, while your second approach looks like the typical normalized database schema that's popular in relational databases.

All of these patterns are applicable in datastores. Remember that in the Datastore API, all "queries" are just local lookups, so performing "an additional query" shouldn't really matter.

Comment: can you send me a syntax for DBList field in DataStore API.Like add an item into DBList And Insert DBList as a field in DbTable.